# Rails 3.2 js not loading in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am restoring an app from a backup on rails 3.2. The app is using spree with a custom template.

In development, it works fine but in production I got js error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slides is not a function

All javascripts break.

I have tried any possible fix like clean and recompile assets or update bundle.

production.rb

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = false
```

On Gemfile, among other things I have

```
gem 'jquery-rails'

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.

        gem 'sass', '3.2.7'
        group :assets do
          gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
          gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
         # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
          gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
          gem 'execjs'
          gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
        end
```

Any suggestions about where I could look?

Comment: Have you run asset compilation on your local production env?

Answer (score 0):

See what the `.slides` error is about, off the top of my head it could be a missing jquery plugin that you throw into vendor/js/ and require in the pipeline.